# Factorize to remove the square root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to factorize $$\pm \sqrt{x^{-6}-x^6-4}$$so that the square root can be removed?

Don't know where to start!

Comment: Please make sure I formatted it correctly.

Comment: $\pm$ $\sqrt[]{x^{-6}-x^{6-4}}$?

Comment: @DisplayName:  Miner was good with parentheses, so I suspect not.

Comment: Ross is correct with the formulation.

Comment: +-sqrt(-x^8 + 2 -x^(-8))=+-i(x^4-x^-4) <---- this is an example

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unlike $-x^8+2-x^{-8}=-(x^4-x^{-4})^2=i^2(x^4-x^{-4})^2,$ the radicand $x^{-6}-x^6-4$ is not factorable as a perfect square, so the given expression is probably the best you're going to get. You could always rewrite it as $$\frac1{|x^3|}\sqrt{1-x^{12}-4x^6},$$ but that isn't really much of an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

$1-x^{12}-4x^6$ and $(1-x^{12}-4x^6)'=-12x^{11}-24x^5$ are coprime, so the given polynomial has not a square multipliers and your question has not a solution.